# Distribute points respect to features using Quantum Gis

Tags: qgis, vector, tools

I want to know if there is any tool to make points with respect to selected features in a theme?
Using: vector, investigating tools, regular points you can do it but not with respect to a selected feature - You obtain a square grid point.

Thanks, Cecilia

Answer (score 5):

after obtaining the square grid, clip it with:
`Vector>Geoprocessing Tools>Intersect`
intersect it with the poligon.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is no one-click solution for this (but feel free to [write an enhancement request](https://trac.osgeo.org/qgis/)).

First, you'll have to export the selected feature(s) using "Save selection as ...".

Then, you can use "Intersect" tool on the regular point layer and the layer containing only your previously selected polygon(s).